# Delete Camera If NOT Local Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

Trying to make camera follow player, but since my game is multiplayer, it can only show the local player. It's a LAN game. I've tried looking and couldn't find anything that would work.

Code:

```
void Start () {

    if (!isLocalPlayer)
        DestroyImmediate(Camera.main.gameObject);

}
```

Comment: is the camera parented to the player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're parenting the camera to a player and then having it instantiate multiple cameras when you create multiplayer instances of the player prefab?

Rather than build the camera into the player, create a single camera, write a basic "follow" script and assign a target to follow when the game starts.

```
public class Follow : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;

    // LateUpdate to prevent camera jitter by allowing the player to move first
    void LateUpdate() {
        transform.position = target.position;
    }
}
```